# Responsive screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> Is there a way/code that I can us to make website fit all screen sizes
>   without using media query in the CSS?
>
> > The style that I am using is the CSS Style, not bootstrap nor flexbox

Comment: Describe your question/problem further. A simple website with one paragraph will effortlessly be responsive on any device. Why do you not want to use media queries anyway?

Comment: I have to create a website that has to display for mobile, desktop, and tablet. But I notice all three devices have different screen size and different resolution. I did a google search for different screen size dimensions and I notice there's so many. I know when I use media query in CSS, I can target different screen sizes to make the right adjustments. 
But I don't know with screen sizes are best to make the adjustments for.

Comment: Also with that in mind, I also have to create a fold for the website. 
knowing that I have to create a fold for the website I don't know where the height with cut off for all screen dimensions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vh` (1% of window height) and `vw` (1% of window width) units in your CSS definitions instead (and `calc(...)` desired values).

Btw. flexbox **is** CSS style and is the next thing you may consider.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
width:100%
```

in your css file for responsive design then it will fixed but if you have 4 div and then you need to use 25% or less. it will work all section but if it is mobile device then total screen size is 500px as like then when you use

```
width:25%
```

[image]
then 4 div will show very small size and it will not good to see this so if you use media query then it will look fine . but percent (%) will work for your purpose

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot, how would develop for each windows height folded ?

Comment: in responsive design width is most important but if you want to fixed height then % and px will work . in this case % will adjust auto as screen and if you use px then if screen is less then scroll will show and if screen is big then screen some section will blank